# Equivalent Mac "cp -X" on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, cp

I'm migrating some bash scripts written for Mac to Linux, in which `cp -X` is used in several places. Some research shows that `cp -X` on Mac is different from `cp -x` on Linux.

The first one means "Do not copy Extended Attributes (EAs) or resource forks" while the latter means "stay on this file system".

So is there an equivalent Mac "cp -X" on Linux?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: This isn't really a `bash` question, btw -- bash doesn't provide `cp`, your OS does. (If it were otherwise, then behavior would be identical between operating systems, so you wouldn't be asking this question). If you're trying to ask about standard UNIX tools, `unix` is the typical tag; if you're asking about those tools in a context where a shell is necessarily involved but *which* shell doesn't matter, then that should generally be either `shell` (to be generic) or `sh` (to tag for the lowest-common-denominator POSIX sh standard).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the clarification. I have removed the unsuitable `bash` tag:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cp` on Linux doesn't copy xattrs by default, and Linux doesn't have resource forks at all.

Thus, you don't need it -- default behavior does what you want.

---

However, if you want to be completely explicit:

```
cp --no-preserve=xattr
```